# Is there a way using Parse server to get realtime objects | objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-server

I am new to Objective c and Parse but if I have an app and I need to get objects when they are created. Like iMessage where it is not checking every few seconds it just gets notified that a new message has been sent to it. In the same way can I have a list of objects reload from parse when a new object is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way that you can do realtime with Parse server. There are two solutions. In my messaging app, I send a push notification to the counterpart. When the notification is delivered, I will call the local Notification Center to update data or the UI.

The second solution would be Firebase. This year after Google I.O. They launched a new version of firebase. Even though the data is organized in a JSON tree, but it now supports almost everything you can imagine. Realtime, file storage, push notification, user authorization...

Please let me know if you have any more questions or details about Parse or Firebase. Good luck.